# Implementing profile page in wordpress

Tags: profiles

I have a php file named 'profile.php' which handles the profile page of a user. Currently the profile url will be like "www.sitename.com/profile/?username=name".
I want to make the profile link like "www.sitename.com/profile/name". How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Is your profile.php is a file inside your theme. If so it's need to be a page template. Then you need to add query vars and add rewrite rule for that query vars .
please read this blog http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/ for reference